# INSERT statement COPY equivalent

Tags: postgresql, insert, copy

I would like to transform this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('JohnDoe');
```

Into a copy equivalent:

```
COPY users (username) FROM ('JohnDoe');
```

What would be a correct syntax for the copy statement?

Comment: The ever helpful documentation to the rescue: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: I already saw the documentation but I'm not able to fit this specific need

Answer (score 3):

The point of `COPY` is to receive the data from **outside** the query.
The closest syntax to what you're asking is

```
COPY users(username) FROM STDIN;
```

If done from within the psql interpreter in interactive mode, it displays this invite:

> Enter data to be copied followed by a newline. End with a backslash
>   and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.

If done from a non-interactive program, dedicated functions can be used to send the data. They're provided by the PostgreSQL driver that the program uses.

Comment: Would not be a valid use case to use COPY for speeding up INSERTS?

Comment: @ImanolY.: that depends on how many inserts you want to do. For a couple of thousands a single INSERT is probably just as fast. For millions of rows COPY is definitely faster

Answer (score 0):

I have found a valid statement with the `PROGRAM` option:

```
COPY users (username) FROM PROGRAM 'echo JohnDoe' DELIMITER ',';
```

With this, I can set dynamically the values without reading a file or use pgsql.

For more than 1 row it's possible to join several echo commands `echo JohDoe & echo JaneDoe`

Comment: But then it will be much slower than INSERT so it's pointless